# Finding the Big-theta notation of a Function

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, big-o

So I have a loop embedded inside a loop here:

```
int a,b,n;
for (a = 1; a <=n; a++) {
    for (b = 0; b < n; b+=a)
        cout << "hey" << endl;
}
```

n is a power of 2

I'm trying to understand how to calculate the Time complexity of this however I'm having trouble figuring out the Big-theta notation for this.

I know that the the outter loop runs in O(n) time, but I'm not sure about the inner loop due to the b+=a. I know that If I had the time for both loops, I could multiply them to get the Big-theta time of the function, but I'm not sure what the inner loop is running at.

When I plug in sample n's (ie. 2, 4, 8, 16), then the inner loop is looped 3, 9, 24, 61 times, respectively. I don't see how these values correlate.

Edit:

Ok I see what you are saying, but I'm trying to compare it to this function. What would the time for this function be? Then i can compare the speed of the two:

```
int a,b,n;
int z = 1;
for (a = 0; a <n; a++) {
    for (b = 0; b < n; b=b+z)
        cout << "hey" << endl;
    z = z * 2;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see that the inner loop runs the amount of times that a is included in n, ie the biggest integer k that satisfies:

[image]

It corresponds to a ceiling function. So the total number of iterations of the inner loop is:

[image]

The second sum is the [Divisor summatory function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_summatory_function), which can be written:

[image]

So the time complexity of the whole code is O(nlogn).

**EDIT**

About the second piece of code you posted, the calculations are simpler. If `n=2^k`, the number of iterations is:

[image]

So the second one is faster since it's a O(n).